# Unable to render form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to import a simple single-field form in Django, and I have gone through plenty of Tutorial Videos on YouTube describing the same. Yet, I'm unable to render the simple form on my web-app. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something really stupid that is still oblivious to me.

I'll also post in the folder structure so you can suggest if I'm defining the class/function in the wrong views.py file.

The appropriate source codes are as follows:

**earthquake/views.py File**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from earthquake.forms import HomeForm
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'earthquake/home.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form1 = HomeForm()
        argf = {
            'myform': form1
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, argf)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    post = forms.CharField()
```

**home.html (snippet)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Query Form</h1>
        <p>Please Enter the parameters you want to query against the USGS Earthquake DB</p>
        <div class="container">
        <form class="" method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ myform }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Django Project urls (interview.py/urls.py)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from interview.views import login_redirect
from interview import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_redirect, name='login_redirect'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('earthquake.urls')),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='earthquake/login.html'), name="login"),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='earthquake/logout.html'), name="logout"),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

**App URLS (interview/earthquake/urls.py)**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

**Folder Structure**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoehT.jpg

(In case you're unable to see the last entry in the image, it's the main *views.py* present in the project folder).

The following is the snapshot of the render I currently get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXR7W.jpg

Comment: Hello Anton, I've added the urls.py files too as requested. Hope you can find something.

Comment: I was previously using a function based render, hence the views.home. Here's the part that was missed out in earthquake/urls my apologies for the same. 

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'earthquake/home.html')

Comment: Can you update your code where that belongs

Comment: Thank you Anton, the problem was as you and Kevin pointed out, I'd defined both a function based render as well as a class based render simultaneously. Changed the urls.py accordingly and it works well now.

Comment: Glad it worked! :)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that in your home views file your class based view is called

`HomeView(TemplateView)`

Yet in your app urls you are including the view as `view.home` when it should be
`view.HomeView`

to add to that, this is a classed based view so your urls page for that should look like:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

Since this is a class based view.

Comment: I guess it was because I was previously using a simple render to check my Home page, but later I'm sure I must have switched to a class based view whilst following a tutorial. Could this be a problem?

If so, could you suggest how I effectively change it into a functional class based view?

Comment: You can keep it as a class view

Comment: Thank you Kevin, the problem was as you and Anton pointed out, I'd defined both a function based render as well as a class based render simultaneously. Changed the urls.py to accomodate the class based view and it works well now. You guys are life-savers.